# SQL запрос ругается что название колонки через '-'

Tags: python, sql

```
import pyodbc
from pprint import pprint
import uuid
import random
import string

count1 = 0
while count1 < 2:
    id1 = random.randint(1, 100)
    uuidx1 = uuid.uuid4()
    letters1 = string.ascii_lowercase
    rand_string1 = ''.join(random.choice(letters1) for i in range(10))
    int1 = random.randint(100, 100000)
    insert_user = f"insert into [dbo].[GUID_Objects] (IACGUID, IACConnector_Guid, IACObjectClass, IACLastMod, IACPreferredLanguage, msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute17) values ('{uuidx1}', '4D032273-BE6A-414B-940D-7F6FD53DA771', 'user', '7/26/2021', '{rand_string1}', '{rand_string1}')"
    count1 += 1
    crsr.execute(insert_user)
    select = 'SELECT IACGUID, IACConnector_Guid, IACObjectClass, IACLastMod, IACPreferredLanguage from [dbo].[GUID_Objects]'
crsr.execute(select)
pprint(crsr.fetchall())
```

Проблема в insert_user. там есть название колонки в таблице msDS-cloudExtensionAttribute17 и ругается как я понимаю на то что там есть '-'. Если этот столбец не заполнять, то отрабатывает корректно. С ним ловлю ошибку:

crsr.execute(insert_user)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '-'. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

Подскажите, как обойти данную ошибку? Подобных колонок с тире в название очень много в таблице с которой работаю и их необходимо заполнить.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901453/sql-standard-to-escape-column-names

Comment: Большое спасибо